# How can I access my .env email variable via controller

Tags: laravel, email

I have quite a few emails that must go to the administrator of the site, which is the email declared in the .env

So, in each mailable that I create, for the $this->to(), I want to add the email defined in the .env so that in case it changes, I dont have to go around each mail and manually change it.

So I tried this just for testing purposes:

```
Route::get('send', function(){
    Mail::send(new AdminEmail());
})->name('test.email');
```

The Mailable looks like this in the constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->from('no-replya@gmail.com', 'Tester');
    $this->to(env("MAIL_USERNAME"), 'Admin');
}
```

In the .env I have the configurations:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=admin@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=z6c4czc44
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

When I try to send the email I see the following error:

```
Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.
```

So it seems like am not managing to access the variable correctly.

How can I access the email from the .env file?

Comment: Have you tried the `env` helper like this: `env('MAIL_USERNAME', 'DEFAULT_VALUE');`
But even better usage is with the config helper, so here `config('mail.username')` this will do the same, having set the username in the `mail.php` config file to use the ENV variable.

Comment: I get this error: Address in mailbox given [DEFAULT_VALUE] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

Comment: check my edited comment, but also I added DEFAULT VALUE to let you know that you can add default mail there to be used in case that variable is not set.

Comment: The config helper function works. Appreciate the support.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `env("MAIL_USERNAME")` try `config('mail.username')`

It first tries to get config variable value in the .env file and if it couldn't find the variable value in the .env file it will get variable value from `config/mail.php`